# Proof of PBW theorem in Humphreys' Lie algebra: intuition for a Lemma

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra with a basis $(x_i:i\in \Omega)$, and $\mathfrak{U}(L)$ the universal enveloping algebra of $L$.

Let $\mathfrak{S}$ denote the symmetric algebra in the variables $z_i$ ($i\in \Omega$).

The essential point in PBW theorem is that given a total order on set $\Omega$, for each non-decreasing sequence $i_1\le i_2\le \cdots \le i_k$ of elements of $I$, the collection of  elements $x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}$ together with $1$ forms a basis of $\mathfrak{U}(L)$. Also, $\mathfrak{U}(L)$ and $\mathfrak{S}$ are isomorphic as associative algebras.

However, the proof of PBW theorem in Humphreys' Lie algebra is based on following Lemma. My question, *what is the intuition to consider such family of maps $f_m$, and why the domain is considered to be $L\otimes S_m$?* [Because the proof of PBW theorem in Jacobson's book is a simple commutator calculus based computation.]

[image]